# Like "sexist" or "racist," but in reference to being gay?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, vocabulary, sexual-minorities

Is there a term that is similar to sexist or racist but refers to gay people? "Homophobic" comes to mind, but that's more a fear or disgust of homosexuals versus discrimination based solely on sexual orientation.

To be specific, I'm looking for an -ist/-ism word, but I'm not sure if one exists.

Comment: *discriminative* or *prejudice* might work, though they are not specific to anti-homosexuality.

Comment: Although the morphology of "homophobic" suggests the meaning "Fear of homosexuals", it is often used in common parlance to refer to the discrimination you describe.  A person who exhibits this can be called a "Homophobe".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*heterosexism* might be what you are looking for.
According to [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heterosexism):

> :  discrimination or prejudice by heterosexuals against homosexuals

This idea is expanded in the [wiki article under the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterosexism#Etymology_and_usage) that states:

> Heterosexism is a system of attitudes, bias, and discrimination in favor of opposite-sex sexuality and relationships. It can include the presumption that other people are heterosexual or that opposite-sex attractions and relationships are the only norm and therefore superior.

Interestingly (also on the wiki page - I highlighted the single-word terms):

> Given this lack of semantic transparency, researchers, outreach workers, critical theorists and LGBT activists have proposed and use terms such as institutionalized homophobia, state(-sponsored) homophobia,[9] sexual prejudice, anti-gay bigotry, straight privilege, The Straight Mind (a collection of essays by French writer Monique Wittig), heterosexual bias, compulsory heterosexuality[10] or the much lesser known terms **heterocentrism**, **homonegativity**, and from gender theory and queer theory, **heteronormativity**. However, not all of these descriptors are synonymous to heterosexism.

Comment: But what homosexuals against homosexuals? Girls can say sexist remarks about other girls; there's no directional quality there.

Comment: With the expanded definition in wiki (I know, a reliable source </s>), one can tell that this term, heterosexism, would also include bias against asexual persons and bisexual persons. (And any other permutations not involving a heterosexual relationship).

Comment: @VampDuc,There's nothing particularly unusual about a member of a particular group insulting their own group; a homosexual can still make "heterosexist" remarks just as a Jew can make anti-semitic remarks.

Comment: @Hellion I understand, but the definitions of racism and sexism (I looked them up) are more general, while heterosexism is _specifically_ from heterosexuals to homosexuals. The wiki article is more spot-on.

Comment: @VampDuc, I suppose that I am really taking issue with the dictionary's assumption that it must come from a particular group of people; that's like expecting that only men can be sexist against women, or that only Asians can be racist against Mexicans, or that only Burkina Fasoans can be anti-semitic.

Comment: @Hellion I know, it is pretty outdated. It kind of reminds me how antiquated the MPC is for today's culture, especially regarding something like rape. This word came out about the same time as the MPC and sexuality / sexual issues have been discussed and explored much more in the public sphere than they were in the late 1960s and 70s.

Comment: @Andrew, what is this "MPC" of which you speak?

Comment: @BrianDonovan Sorry, MPC is Modal Penal Code. Loads of law prof. types got together to try to standardize crimes across the US. They have some very good thoughts. And some very bad ones. It just struck me of the similarity between the definition of heterosexism and the definition of rape where a husband can't rape his wife in the MPC. Something that is obviously incorrect but at the time, I suppose, seemed right. (Sorry, it is a bit off topic.)

Comment: It's well nigh impossible to find an extant term that will cover all possible variables, +1 for your effort.

Comment: I believe that only Burkina Fascists are antisemitic.